# Primefaces: Drag and Drop in 1 DataGrid

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a question about the DataGrid and drag and drop. I have several examples between 2 DataGrid or DataTable found. But I need Drag and Drop within a DataGrid. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that it could not be possible ?

Comment: no, but I have found no example of this.

Comment: Using `p:draggable` you can certainly achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

I try to better explain what the problem is.
Hier is my simple code:

```html
        <h:outputText id="id1" value="Test 1" style="width: 30%;"/>
        <h:outputText value="Test 2" style="width: 30%"/>
        <h:outputText value="Test 3" style="width: 30%"/>
        <h:outputText value="Test 4"/>
        <h:outputText value="Test 5"/>
        <h:outputText >
        <p:droppable  tolerance="fit" activeStyleClass="slotActive" onDrop="handleDrop" datasource="display">

                </p:droppable>
         </h:outputText>

        <p:draggable for="id1" revert="true" />

    </h:panelGrid>
```

and my idea is: **Test 1** to **Test 6**

I don't know how it works.